# Hide show image button based on other column values

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a `Grid View` where i have 2 columns (Rating and star). In star column I am showing 5 `imagebuttons`. What I want is if rating is 1 I want only one star (image button) to be visible,if rating is 2 then 2 image buttons and similarly till 5.
Below is my image `TemplateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" />                                       
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server"  ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Rating` is an integer, you can use inline code

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# int.Parse(Eval("rating").ToString()) >= 1 ? true : false %>' />                                       
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# int.Parse(Eval("rating").ToString()) >= 2 ? true : false %>' />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# int.Parse(Eval("rating").ToString()) >= 3 ? true : false %>' />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server"  ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# int.Parse(Eval("rating").ToString()) >= 4 ? true : false %>' />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="/eur/Home/OfferLetter/images/delete_icon.gif" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# int.Parse(Eval("rating").ToString()) >= 5 ? true : false %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```